# How to pass float argument in predict function of scikit linear regression?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am using [scikit linear regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) - single variable to predict y from x. The argument is in float datatype. How can i transform the float into numpy array to predict the output ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
import sys

colnames = ['charge_time', 'running_time']
data = pandas.read_csv('trainingdata.txt', names=colnames)
data = data[data.running_time < 8]
x = np.array(list(data.charge_time))
y = np.array(list(data.running_time))

clf = linear_model.LinearRegression() # Creating a Linear Regression Modal
clf.fit(x[:,np.newaxis], y) # Fitting x and y array as training set
data = float(sys.stdin.readline()) # Input is Float e.g. 4.8
print clf.predict(data[:,np.newaxis]) # As per my understanding parameter should be in 1-D array.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a suggestion not directly related to your question:
You don't need to do `x = np.array(list(data.charge_time))`, you can directly call `x = np.array(data.charge_time)` or, even better, `x = data.charge_time.values` which directly returns the underlying ndarray.

It is also not clear to me why you're adding a dimension to the input arrays using `np.newaxis`.

Regarding your question, `predict` expects an array-like parameters: that can be a list, a numpy array, or other.

So you should be able to just do `data = np.array([float(sys.stdin.readline())])`. Putting the float value in a list (`[]`) is needed because without it numpy would create a 0-d array (i.e. a single value, which is not sliceable) instead of a 1-d array.

Comment: Actually you should add ``[:, newaxis]``, as scikit-learn really wants to have a 2d array. If you pass it a 1d array, depending on the class, it might be interpreted as either one data point or one feature at the moment :-/